# How to create multiple pages on React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, react-router

So I've check multiple posts and websites and I can't get it to work. It just renders a white screen with a the navbar.
This is the code:

App.js:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <Nav/>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/about' element={About}/>
    </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode><App/></React.StrictMode>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Some component:

```
<Link to="/about" className="btn btn-colored">Launch</Link>
```

The 'About' component is working cause I've tested and imported into App.js so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first import the component you want to render

For example you want to render About component so you would import the About component

1. Import the component

import About from "./pages/About";

2. Fix the syntax as in react-jsx we write it in </> brackets.

<Route path='/about' element={} />

Comment: [Please do not use, recommend or link to w3schools.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)